# How to read multiple text files in java for GUI use - didnt find the answer

Tags: java, user-interface

guys i am all new  in java and i looked to the past questions but i didnt find an answer which i understand..
i want to read some text files and use them in multiple JcomboBox and Jlists by using ArrayLists
i am looking to get the at the same time and then i want to reach each one alone with a Listener lets say i have 3 text files(schools , classes , stundents) and 2 of them in 2 JcomboBox and the 3rd in the Jlist .. and i want to get the classes in the combobox when i select the school .. and to get the students in the Jlist when i select the class and so on ..
well i know how to read a text file but is there any easy way to read more than one at the same time ?? or i need to write for each one this code :

```
fr = new FileReader("c.txt");

br = new BufferedReader(fr);

list = new ArrayList<String>();     
while ((s = br.readLine()) !=null){
    list.add(s);
                }
```

Comment: create a utility method that accept List of filename in String, and return the result as a List?

Comment: can you gave me a link to know how can i do that ?? thank you

Comment: If you are asking how to read multiple files with the same block of code, cf. my answer below. If you are asking about reading them **at the same time**, have a look at [concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) (keep in mind that Swing is not considered to be thread-safe!).

Comment: yeah i am looking to get the at the same time and then i want to reach each one alone with a Listener 
lets say i have 3 text files(schools , classes , stundents) and 2 of them in 2 JcomboBox and the 3rd in the Jlist ..
and i want to get the classes in the combobox when i select the school .. and to get the students in the Jlist when i select the class

Comment: Where are the files stored?

Comment: in the same project directory

Comment: @javroid: Okay, I see. In this case concurrency isn't an issue. If you have a fixed (and small) number of files, you could read them into variables all at once (with the for loop mentioned in my answer) and link them up with `if`s or `case - switch`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a method that shows you how you could read some files in a directory and then make use of a nice data structure called HashMap.
This HashMap contains as key the filename and as value it has the content of the designated file. It is made with Java 8 und thus you should have your specs specced according to these specs. Other than that you only have to create some files in your root directory of the project and then run this code. After the runment of aforementioned code is completed, thou are being shown some output for testing purposes.

Have a nice day and I hope you can adapt this code to your needs... aka... not using the main method but instead calling it upon application start... and then by using references to the HashMap from within your UI you can populate your lists.

```
package filereader;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files; 
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class FileReader {
    /**
     * Run this class in a project setup where you have some files in the root
     * dir of the project. This main method will then read these files and 
     * create a HashMap with key(filename)->val(ArrayList<String> content) assignments.
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        //this hashmap will store filename->content
        //you can access it by fileMap.get(filename) and it will return 
        //the corresponding ArrayList that you can then use to retrieve data
        //off of it by. Tha data is the deserialized content of the file.

        HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> fileMap = new HashMap<>();
        List<Path> files;
        Files.list(new File(".").toPath()).
                filter((path) -> {
                    //add more filters here
                    return path.toFile().isFile();
                }
            ).forEach(path -> {
            try {
                ArrayList<String> content = (ArrayList<String>) Files.readAllLines(path);
                //if necessary, add some behaviour as to how the content should be formatted
                //here!
                fileMap.put(path.getFileName().toString(), content);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("This hideous man is a hero! He maked IOEXCeptian ;-(");
                Logger.getLogger(FileReader.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        });

        //lookie lookie content. just for testing.

        fileMap.forEach((k,v)  -> {
            System.out.println(k);
            System.out.println(v);
        });

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FileReader.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Put the files into some kind of [Collection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html), then loop through them with, e.g., a [for-loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html).

This way you don't have to re-type the same code over and over again. Also, have a good read of the tutorials at Oracle, especially the nuts and bolts section.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
File dir = new File(directoryPath);
File[] files = dir.listFiles();
```

Pass your directory path as `directoryPath`, It will give you `File[]` use this file array for your further operations.

Read file

```
 for(File file : files){
       System.out.println(getFileContentsByFileObject(file));  
      //contents of your file
    }
```

`getFileContentsByFileObject(File file)` api return file contents as `String`

```
    public static String getFileContentsByFileObject(File file){
            BufferedReader br = null;
            // comment
            StringBuilder comment = new StringBuilder();

            try{
                br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                String line; 
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    comment.append(line);
                }
            }catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace(); 
            }
            return comment.toString();
        }
```